# Get Image with its description and display

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, telerik

Here is my Script for Displaying Image and Image Heading from Database

```
          <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
            <div class="product">        
<img id='base64image' ' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,#:fileData#' />
                    <span class="k-label"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Heading: </span><span id="lblHeading" class="k-label"> </span>                        
                </div>
        </script>
```

Here is code for the dataSource

```
           var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "SomeURL", type: "get",
                        success: function (data) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                $('#lblHeading').val(data[i].fileDesc);
                            }
                        },
                        datatype: "json"
                    }
                },
            pageSize: 15
            });
```

This is Pager

```
           $("#pager").kendoPager({
            dataSource: dataSource
        });
```

I am getting all the images but with that I also want Image Heading (lblHeading). I do not know why it is not getting displayed in ('#lblHeading') label.. Can anyone please let me know what I am missing.?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It solved by following code

```
<span class="k-label"> #:fileDesc# </span>
```

Silly Mistake